# Looping over a list of data frames and calculate the correlation coefficient

Tags: r

I am using R-Studio the latest version.

I have created a bunch of data frames that I would like to test for correlation. After creating the data frames I created a variable `u` that denotes the universe of all the data frames. I would like to create a loop that will go through each `data.frame` in `u` and do the following test `corr(data.frame)`

I have the following code:

```
corrvals <- NULL
for (i in seq(along=u[])) {
corrvals <- corr(u)
}
```

I found something sort of along the lines of what I want to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845256/calculate-correlation-by-aggregating-columns-of-data-frame/)

The thing is, all the `data.frame`'s are setup exactly how I want them, and I simply would like to run though every `data.frame` in the list and run the `corr` function on it.

I would also like to print out the name of the data.frame and its correlation value, as so:

```
data.frame Corr
ac         -0.03445345
af          0.023429
.
.
.
n           corr(n)
```

into my empty storage container `corrvals`.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to put your data.frames into a list and then run `lapply`.
Like this:

```
# setting up a reproducible example
data(mtcars)
data(iris)
# remove the last column cause it ain't numeric.
iris <- iris[,-5]
listOfDataFrames <- list()
listOfDataFrames[[1]] <- mtcars
listOfDataFrames[[2]] <- iris

# here's a one liner using base R. 
lapply(listOfDataFrames,cor)
```

Welcome to SO, btw.
Ah, I guess you mean `cor`, right? However this works with basically any function.

Comment: yes I did mean `cor` thank you, I don't need a weight correlation

Answer (score 4):

I seem to post a lot of `lapply` on here. It's a convenient wrapper that hides the loop, but does exactly what you want...

## Edit

A little more involved as you want the names. Also the `corr` function is from package `boot`:

```
u <- list( df1 , df2 , df3 )
attr(u, "names") <- c("df1","df2","df3")
require( boot )
res <- lapply( u , function(x) { names(x) ; corr(x) } )

res
#$df1
#[1] 0.353647

#$df2
#[1] 0.4494202

#$df3
#[1] -0.003907642
```

Comment: Yes, but most of its code is in `C` as opposed to just `apply`.

Comment: @Arun I know, but I always get told off for implying that it's not a loop, so I thought that this time I would be explicit! :-)